# How come the role of the Apis mellifera is determined by nutrition rather than chromosomes?

Tags: genetics, asexual-reproduction, bees, haplodiploid

Prior to making my question I browsed on similiar question such as [this one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45507/how-genetically-similar-are-worker-ants-from-the-same-colony) but it doesn't specifically addressed my doubt in the sense that it is related with a different species and on a concept not mentioned in that question. More specifically on whether does nutrition may influence genetics on the sex determination or not?.

My doubt arises as I'm learning about *Partheneogenesis* and *genetic determination of the sex*. Upon reading this [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_bee) in Wikipedia, it explains that a queen bee of the *Apis mellifera* is determined during the development of the larva. **The article doesn't state anything about the chromosomes of the larva.** It just states that the queen will develop into that by feeding it from royal jelly, from which I believe it has some sort of protein that may influence the development of such larva giving it their characteristics.

But this topic is letting me confused. *Does this means that for example a male bee can become into the queen?*.

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis#Insects) explains that some insects produce haploid males from unfertilized eggs by I believe Partheneogenesis. But if the bee doesn't mate, how is the sex determined?. I believe that it will produce only females (as his genetic sex determining chromosome is ZW?) and as such will yield only females, but if the queen does successfuly mate with a male may produce males which in turn can also lay eggs (by Partheneogenesis) and those eggs will all be males?.

From this I'm getting the conclusion that it can occur that some individuals may be all females or all males?.

How come is it possible for an haploid organism get into full develpment isn't it necessary to be diploid?. Do they become into diploid at some moment?.

Can someone help me to clear out this doubt?. This topic has left me confused, so an answer which would help me the most is some sort of explanation on the concepts of partheneogenesis and sex determination in the bees.

Comment: Where did you read that bees have ZW sex determination system?

Comment: The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Unresearched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. ——— Searching for ["sex determination in bees"](https://www.google.com/search?q=sex+determination+in+bees&oq=sex+determination+in+bees) leads to multiple pages such that should help you.

Comment: @BagiM I concluded this from reading at the wikipedia page on Partheneogenesis but of course I could be wrong, hence the necessity of an answer which could clear this doubt.

Comment: @tyersome I'm sorry but I disagree. If you read with attention I started my question by saying that I made an initial effort into looking for answers in Wikipedia. Not only this but I also browsed for similar questions on this community, but yet I'm unable to understand. Thus I require some sort of answer which could address my doubts.

Comment: You say you made an effort, but I'm suggesting you can (and should) do more — e.g. by doing some reading based on the previous comments and correcting the mistakes in your post. ———— This is not a forum or tutorial service; it is a Q&A site where *specific* questions relating to biology get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and [ask] a good question.

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: So you have read the sentence: "Among species with the haplo-diploid sex-determination system, such as hymenopterans (ants, bees and wasps) and thysanopterans (thrips), haploid males are produced from unfertilized eggs." And you concluded the sex determination system in bees is ZW???