# What determines sex in birds?

Tags: genetics, ornithology, sex-determination

Is there production of TDF in birds? If so which gene produces it?

Answer (score 3):

**Sex Determination System**

Birds have a [ZW sex determination system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZW_sex-determination_system) meaning that males are the homogametic sex. Or yet, in other words, males have two Z chromosomes while females have one Z and one W chromosome. You might want to have a look at [Do males of all sexual species have Y chromosomes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27511/do-males-of-all-sexual-species-have-y-chromosomes) for a short review of the diversity of sex determination system.

**Dosage compensation**

In birds dosage compensation exist but appear quite different than in mammals ([Mank and Ellegren, 2009](https://www.nature.com/articles/hdy2008116); [Mank et al., 2011](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1558-5646.2011.01316.x/abstract); [Uebening et al., 2015](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/32/10/2716/1211529); [Naurin et al. 2009](http://www.cell.com/trends/genetics/fulltext/S0168-9525(09)00234-0?_returnURL=http%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0168952509002340%3Fshowall%3Dtrue))

**Sex determining locus**

The DMRT1 gene on the Z chromosome appears to be important for male sex determination by affecting the testicular marker, SOX9 however it might not be the whole story ([Smith et al. 2009](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature08298)). It is possible that several loci are involved in determining sex in birds.