# What is the X-chromosome responsible for?

Tags: chromosome, sex-chromosome

I understand that the X-chromosome is responsible for certain disorders, like red-green colorblindness; but besides disorders, what do the genes on the X-chromosome determine?

Comment: The number of genes on the X chromosome approaches 1000 and thus your question is too broad for this site.

Comment: @canadianer Could just give some general things that these genes would be responsible for, or is it too broad?

Comment: "besides disorders" - it's not a complete answer, but for info it's not really helpful to think of genes as 'coding for' a disorder. Any gene that does anything useful can get broken, and when it does the severity of the consequences depends on how important its normal function is.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more of your thinking here, and show what research you have done before asking?

Comment: @arboviral I agree with what you have said. I phrased the question that way because I had only known that genes on the X-chromosome were responsible for certain disorders until that point.

Comment: @CMK My point was more that it's more accurate to think of them as responsible for whatever's broken in the disorder. So the *lack* of a properly functioning gene for [...] results in a disorder. Otherwise some people are bound to think "hey, why don't we just delete the gene and then nobody will get the disorder".

Comment: @arboviral Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=X%5BCHR%5D+AND+human%5BORGN%5D) is the list! There are about 900 protein coding genes and about 500 non-coding transcribed sequences. It is not going to be feasible to explain you the function of every single one of those genes. Your question is hence too broad.

You will find [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_chromosome#Gene_list) a small subset of those ~900 genes.

If your question was

> Are all genes that are on the X chromosome related to sex?

Then, the answer is "no". Most of them have nothing to do with gender specific traits.

Comment: Where did the quoted section in your answer come from? (I agree it sounds like that is the misapprehension that prompted the question, but I don't see it anywhere.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the links, although I would he lying if I said that I understood what they were saying. However, concerning the genes involved with sex determination, what do those genes determine, in fact?

Comment: I have changed "sec determination" with "gender specific trait". That was a typo. In humans, there are only one gene affecting sex determination, it is SRY (coding for [TDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testis-determining_factor)) present on the Y chromosome. I don't know much else about eventual gender specific beneficial genes on the X chromosome.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Do males of all sexual species have Y chromosomes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27511/do-males-of-all-sexual-species-have-y-chromosomes)

Comment: @Remi.b Thank you for your response. What is your opinion on this article, which says that there is more than one gene that affects sex determination? https://genderedinnovations.stanford.edu/case-studies/genetics.html#tabs-2

Comment: I only just read the first few sentences. I am not so surprised that with severe medical intervention such as a gonadectomy or large injection of male hormone in females, you can masculinized or feminize the individuals. In principle, it is completely possible that several loci affect sex determination (it is the case in many species), I just had never heard such claims in mammals.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to start the answer by mentioning that I was fortunate to attend a lecture by [Jenny Graves](http://www.latrobe.edu.au/she/staff/profile?uname=jgraves), a scientist working on X chromosomes recently.
In her lecture she mentioned the genes on X-chromosomes as "brain and balls" genes. As Remi.b has already added a [list](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=X%5BCHR%5D%20AND%20human%5BORGN%5D) you can go through it to find a few of these genes. I am highlighting a few of them as follows:-

1. [Androgen receptor](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/367) (AR) - Required for prostrate formation in males. Mutations may lead to muscular degeneration and loss of motor control ([Kennedy's syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinal_and_bulbar_muscular_atrophy)).
2. [AIFM1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/9131) - An inhibitor of apoptosis. Mutations may lead to neurodegenerative conditions like [Charcot-Marie-Tooth disease 4](https://www.omim.org/entry/310490).
3. [MeCP2](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P51608) - Heterozygous female *MeCP2* mutants suffer from [Rett Syndrome](https://www.omim.org/entry/312750?search=rett%20syndrome&highlight=syndromic%20syndrome%20rett). It is almost exclusively seen in females because male mutant embryos die during pregnancy.
4. BEX1, BEX2 and BEX4 - Brain-expressed X-linked (BEX) proteins

Also regarding sex determination - the mammalian XY sex determination is Y centered i.e. the [*SRY*](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/SRY#conditions) gene on the Y chromosome is the gene responsible for determining maleness. Interestingly some species not using the XY system have evolved female specific sex determination genes. I will add relevant citations when I have time.

Comment: I added a few relevant citations because someone downvoted without providing a reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, does this mean that the X+chromosome contains genes that direct the formation of part of the male reproductive system?

Comment: Yes. Since, the size of the Y chromosome is much smaller than X chromosome it does not contain many genes. Most of the genes on Y are only involved in early determination of sex. Information regarding organ development is still encoded by X.

Comment: @CMK Also consider upvoting if the answer satisfies your curiosity.

Comment: Thank you. I would upvote, but my reputation isn't high enough. I'm sorry about that. But, just to be clear, the X-chromosome does direct The formation of the male reproductive in part?

Comment: @CMK Yes, it does. The androgen receptor (AR) being on the X is a clear indicator of the fact. If you take a look at the list Remi provided i am sure you will find a few more genes involved in male development. I will go through the lis and let you know if I find a few as well.

Comment: Okay, thank you for this. It has been extremely helpful. Would this, then, mean that female is not the default gender as many people say, or is this conclusion gratuitous based on this fact? Thank you.

Comment: Female is called the default gender because in absence of *SRY* gene all embryos develop to be females. Loss of function *SRY* mutant XY genotype gives rise to female babies. Although these individuals require hormonal supplements for proper development during puberty. Link for syndrome - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_gonadal_dysgenesis

Comment: I understand. However, I read elsewhere that there are genes which required to suppress male development and promote female development. It's found in this article. https://genderedinnovations.stanford.edu/case-studies/genetics.html#tabs-2