# What animal classes has also "Like Humans" XY Chromosomes for Males and XX for Females?

Tags: genetics, dna

Are other mammals. birds, reptiles, or even insects same to humans in that the male organisms have XY Chromoson at the end and female XX?

Thanks for the ansver

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_sex-determination_system

Comment: specifically from that Wikipedia link: " humans, most other mammals, some insects (Drosophila), some snakes, some fish (guppies), and some plants (Ginkgo) tree"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do males of all sexual species have Y chromosomes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27511/do-males-of-all-sexual-species-have-y-chromosomes)

Answer (score 1):

In mammals, Y chromosome determines the sex. SRY gene present on Y chromosome is responsible for sex determination. And, in absence of this gene results in female sex. Non-human mammals use several genes on the Y chromosome.

Platypus and Drosophila also uses XY sex determination system, but in different way. Like in platypus, combination of genes present on XY chromosome are used to determine sex characteristics. And in drosophila, two X chromosome gives female characteristics, and Y chromosome determines maleness.

**Reference:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_sex-determination_system